# AngularJS ng-repeat performance troubles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optimization

Yea I know that there was a lot of question about performance but there wasn't any answer which would help me.

My HTML

```
<select ng-model="model" class="form-control">
     <option ng-repeat="item in list" value="{{item.Description}}">{{item.Description}}</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$scope.list= items; // about 300 objects
```

My problem is performance, on firefox/chrome/opera it's bearable but on IE 11 it's so laggy that I'm getting

> localhost is not responding due to a long-running script.

If I delete this select, everything is ok.
Also I was trying to add track by item.ID but it didn't help.

Do you have any ideas how to optimize it?
Thanks for your help!

I'm using AngularJS in version 1.3.4

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into paging or lazy loading the details.

Comment: Pagination in select? How does it work? @epascarello

Comment: Ah, did not see it was a select... seems like select is a very bad choice for 300 selections. But does it improve if you do: `ng-repeat="item in ::list"`

Comment: Already from a user experience point of view, select is definitely the wrong choice for 300 options...

Comment: @epascarello Thanks but it didn't help

Comment: @Fissio so how should I implement it?

Comment: @Icet Use autocomplete / typeahead to reduce the number of options the user has to scroll through

Comment: A select with 300 options should not be laggy at all. Is that really everything you have when it comes to HTML and functionality? Do you have any `ng-mouseover` or something else that continuously triggers the digest loop? http://plnkr.co/edit/7gjaJPlk157zTwGg5Rqb?p=preview

Comment: It's all i don't have any other ng-xxx, I'm getting from service this data but it's really fast so it's not an problem @tasseKATT